# RESTFul WS over HTTPS and Java Client

Tags: rest, java1.4

I have to develop a RESTful client in Java 1.4 (Constraint). This client should call the WS over SSL (Https). I was able to call the WS successfully over http but https is going over my head. Please explain me what to do and how to import certificates etc. Also i am using vanilla Java 1.4 no third part API. I have gone through many of the comments / posts here but none of them is working for me.

Please help.

Comment: Is it a constraint that you cannot use a third party library?

Comment: If you can use third party libraries, httpclient 3.x works with Java 1.4 and has a page about working with SSL [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).